# Greenhouse or compression?

Tags: climate-science

Convection driven compressional warming is accepted here on Earth by scientists( Chinook winds, Santa Anna winds) when there is such low pressure, 1 bar = 14 psi. Scientists also agree that Jupiter’s lower atmosphere is as hot as the Sun for the same reason, convection driven  compressional heating.
My question. With 90 bar pressure difference, 1300 psi , and 700c temperature difference from the surface of the planet to the top of the convection system, wouldn’t the convection driven  compressional warming alone be enough to explain the incredible heat on Venus?

Answer (score 0):

Any convection driven pressure changes within a planetary atmosphere will include heating from compression *and cooling from decompression*, in approximately equal amounts. It cannot add or remove any heat in the atmosphere - or maintain the heat already within it, ie prevent it's loss over time to space. The high temperature of Venus' atmosphere is maintained by incoming heat from the Sun in balance with the heat going out. Without the Greenhouse Effect the temperature on Venus would be expected to be around 66 C degrees instead of around 460.